# Xampp 7.0.1 Apache crashes when I use session_start()

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When I start a session using session_start() in PHP my Apache server just stops working.

I am using Xampp 7.0.1 for Windows.

My config file looks like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//session_start();
//ob_start();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

//Rest of the code
?>
```

Even if I put it on the first line of the file it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

---

The weird thing is that it is only happening in this specific map structure.

i.e.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\*
```

In for example:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\*
```

It works fine.

Comment: Check apache's errorlog

Comment: @CharlotteDunois What do I need to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=248203&sid=0d197e14e20a9a920f0de8e11a662f41) is the solution, it's XAMPP bug and they are currently fixing it. If that didn't work, try to wait for XAMPP 7.0.2 or downgrade until fix comes out.

> we have been checking the configuration of XAMPP and we found that the
>   issue is related to the use_only_cookies variable that you can find in
>   the Session's section of the php.ini file. Apache will crash if the
>   use_only_cookies variable in the Session's section is set to 0 and
>   everything is fine if it's set to 1.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies
>
> We also checked that the use_strict_mode should be set to 1.
>
> https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_sessions
>   http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode
>
> We'll include those changes in the next version of XAMPP with PHP 7.
>   We are building the installers with the version 7.0.2 and we'll
>   release them as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you should set session.save_path in your php.ini
please also make sure you have php.ini with correct settings.
create an index.php and `echo phpinfo();` ensure all required services is on.